# How do you create a private Facebook group with only yourself in it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I was wondering if it is possible to create a private Facebook group that only consists of you in it and no one else in it.

Creating such a group might be great for taking advantage of the files upload feature that Facebook recently turned on for groups, or maybe just to do some basic testing of the groups feature without affecting anyone or revealing what you have done.

Was anyone successful in creating such a group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the group by using the new group link at the sidebar, fill in the name and put the privacy as secret. Before clicking on create, you should add one other friend in to the group and click create.

When you enter your new group, click on the Members tab and remove the friend that you added and you have your own private group.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Click on the new Group link and create a group as "Secret Group." Never invite or add anyone to this group.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This is not possible. You have to enter someone's name into the Members: column, you can't just leave it blank.